# Left join MIS-MATCH from ACTUAL values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

After multiple time trying I'm unable to fix this left join query. My query returns different `debit_amount` from the actual whereas my actual `debit_amount` is lesser than the given for both of months.

My question is why my left join values mismatch from actual and how can I fix this to get actual values.

My complete query and results are shown below.

```
SELECT 
    MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date) as month,
    IFNULL(SUM(cc.credit_amount),0) AS credit,
    IFNULL(SUM(cd.debit_amount),0) AS debit_amount,
    MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date) AS month
FROM 
    cust_credit AS cc
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         ((cd.debit_date)), 
         IFNULL(SUM(cd.debit_amount), 0) AS debit_amount 
     FROM 
         cust_debit AS cd 
     GROUP BY 
         MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date)) cd ON ((MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date)) = MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date))
GROUP BY 
    MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date)
```

Result of that query in a screenshot:

[image: JOIN QUERRY]

While if I run only `join` to chec. the query is

```
  SELECT (MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date)) , IFNULL(SUM(cd.debit_amount),0) AS debit_amount FROM cust_debit AS cd GROUP BY MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date )
```

Results of that query:

[[image: RESULT IMAGE[2]]

CREDIT TABLE

[image: cust_credit]

DEBIT TABLE

[image: cust_debit]

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Thanks  for your time , my question why my `left join ` values mismatch from actual and how can i fix this ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Incidentally, and not that it matters much, but COALESCE() conforms to the ANSI standard.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Put such an image inline, not as a link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per theory, `LEFT JOIN` will give you data, which is common between table and additionally from left table.

So, it has more chance that, you will get more rows in case of `LEFT JOIN` compare to `INNER JOIN` or directly selecting row from one of the table.

Now, you will look the the query, you have made join on below condition.

```
ON ( (MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date)) = MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date))
```

So, you will get all rows from `cust_credit` table and additionally where above condition satisfies.

**==Update==**

This is sample SQL, you might need to make changes accordingly. So, you are trying to get all credit and debit for specific month. This can be achieved in simple `INNER JOIN` between the tables.

```
SELECT cd.month, cc.credit_amount, cd.debit_amount FROM 
(SELECT 
MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date) as month,
IFNULL(SUM(cc.credit_amount),0) AS credit_amount
FROM
cust_credit cc 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date)) cc

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT 
MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date) as month,
IFNULL(SUM(cd.debit_amount),0) AS debit_amount
FROM
cust_debit cd
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date)) cd ON cc.month=cd.month;
```

Comment: On directly selecting I'll get my actual results , and i attached that `querry` and reulten image in my question. what chnages I have to made to fix this and second thing i also tried `inner join` thats also have same result. You're right my rows are sum up i know that, how can i fix this that my question. Thanks for your time and sorry fo my bad english, kindly help me out.

Comment: @Newbees I gave you theory. Now, I don't know, what are you trying to achieve. So, I'm not sure what suggestion I should give

Comment: Sir, all i want is to sum up all credit and debit for same months, thats all, will you guide me for that ?

Comment: @Newbees Why don't you simply use inner join between table. I will update in a while

Comment: @Newbees I have added SQL to my post, please note, this may give you expected output, but if not, then you need to make changes accordingly. As we can't code exactly for you. You have to learn yourself.

Comment: sir still facing same issue, the issue is with **ON** clause... thats what i think...and i dont know how to fix it...

Comment: @Newbees what issue ?

Comment: My credit and debit table does not contain a unique column `id` so i can't use `ON` caluse on `id` and I wanna used `MONTHNAME` basis. Look at my question ,`LEFT JOIN QUERRY` **RESULT IMAGES** In actual my `debit_amount =1958` while using join it will `1958*7=13706`. Thats my issue how can i stop this seven times multiplication.

Comment: @Newbees who said, you need unique value to use ON?? Did you executed the query, which I posted ?

Comment: `ON cc.cust_id=cd.cust_id` doesn't means sum up on same id's ?

Comment: @Newbees NO. please execute the query and  you will see.

Comment: All values are different, the result is...
month......| credit  | debit_amount.........
December       | 126     |3801............
January           |6557    |5170...........

Comment: @Newbees I'm not sure what are you talking about *All values are different*  It will group the data with month and all the debit and credit will be summed for each month. I don't know, what are you expecting from SQL to do

Comment: your querry result is..
https://ibb.co/bTpfyb
while acutal values of debit table
https://ibb.co/jmPPPG
while acutal values of credit table
https://ibb.co/fjNiJb

Comment: @Newbees Now, I understand, what are you trying to achieve. First of all, you table design is worst. I will make changed to SQL in a while. Do close this post immediate by upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: Definitely I'll,kindly guide me how can i improve my table design, I'm very tahnakful please :( and hows it is worst...

Comment: @Newbees I have updated the SQL, because it should have gave you correct output when I gave you SQL at first. You need to learn about normalization in short and Google is your friend.

Comment: kindly let me know about the topics name which i need to cover, thanks

Comment: @Newbees I hope, you have got the result, what you were expecting. Do upvote this answer. Also, try to learn something yourself with minimal guidance. This will help you to improve

Comment: sir will you give one more favour ?

Comment: @Newbees If you have any other question, you are supposed to post it. and provide complete details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48421351/how-to-stop-this-repetition-and-group-by-date
this is the link of that question, thanks ....