# How to stop this repetition and group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

After multiple attempts I'm unable to get my required result from this  **query**.

```
SELECT 
cc.date as credi_date,
cd.date as debit_date,
cd.month AS month,
ROUND(IFNULL(cc.credit_amount,0),2) AS credit,
ROUND(IFNULL(cd.debit_amount,0),2) AS debit
FROM 
(SELECT
DATE(cc.credit_date) as date,
MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date) as month,
IFNULL(SUM(cc.credit_amount),0) AS credit_amount
FROM
cust_credit cc 
WHERE YEAR(cc.credit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY DATE(cc.credit_date)) cc

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT
 DATE(cd.debit_date) as date,
MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date) as month,
IFNULL(SUM(cd.debit_amount),0) AS debit_amount
FROM
cust_debit cd
WHERE YEAR(cd.debit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY DATE(cd.debit_date)) cd ON cc.month=cd.month
```

The problem is that this query repeats the `rows` multiple times. I don't know what thing cause this repetition and how can fix this. The `image` of result is given below.

[image: Result]

**My required result is**

[image: Required]

My credit table is give below

[image: credit table]

My debit table is give below

[image: debit table]

Comment: I'm not sure that you really need to use subqueries. Have you tried place a DISTINCT after SELECT, use cust_credit and cust_debit directly instead of subqueries and GROUP the result? Also check your INNER JOIN conditions

Comment: Why don't you use DISTINCT clause?

Comment: @kiks73 no, i dont tried DISTINCT, and the issue is with `ON` clause.

Comment: @GarimaGupta is it better way ?

Comment: @GarimaGupta facing same issue ...

Comment: @Newbees Was your problem solved ?

Comment: @Ravi no sir...

Comment: @Newbees I'm sure, I might have told you, your table design is wrong. Now, see the problem yourself. Now, I don't know what should be your correct design. As I don't know the business requirement of your app. But, will look after sometime

Comment: @Newbees I have updated the answer, let me know, if it solves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon should use a UNION in the subquery and then GROUP BY in the SELECT:

```
SELECT my_date, 
       my_month, 
       SUM(credit), 
       SUM(debit)
FROM (
    SELECT cc.credit_date as my_date,
           MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date) as my_month,
           ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(cc.credit_amount,0)),2) AS credit,
           0 AS debit
    FROM   cust_credit cc
    WHERE YEAR(cc.credit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
    GROUP BY cc.credit_date,
             MONTHNAME(cc.credit_date)
    UNION
    SELECT 
           cd.debit_date ,
           MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date) ,
           0 ,
           ROUND(SUM(IFNULL(cd.debit_amount,0)),2)
    FROM   cust_debit cd
    WHERE YEAR(cd.debit_date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
    GROUP BY cd.debit_date, 
             MONTHNAME(cd.debit_date) 
) as TT
GROUP BY my_date,my_month
```

[This is the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c69966/15)

Comment: done sir... thanks a lot, i make little bit changes in your answer to get required result...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your result is cross join between two query and that's the reason your are getting cross product i.e. `total number of rows from credit x total number of rows from debit`.

Because, month for all rows in debit and credit tables are same (i.e. `January`). But, you have unique `date` in both table

So, making below change should give you expected output.

```
ON cc.month=cd.month
```

to

```
ON cc.date = cd.date
```

Comment: right , but if there is no credit transiction tak place on a specfic date and debit transiction took place, like `2018-01-10` whic is given in question in `required image` than the result is nothing would will be -display if i used `WHERE` clause on `credit_date = debit_date` ! so what how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: @Newbees for that you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which is not present in `MySQL` it seems. But work around is , use `LEFT` and `UNION` together.

Comment: @Newbees But, wait I see there is a row in credit table for `2018-01-10` for amount `0`.

Comment: this querry is working but not for all  it skipped themany dates from debit table ... and second thing let, there is no row in `credit table` of some date but present in `debit table` of table, than did you think, that will work `ON cc.date = cd.date` ?

Comment: @Newbees If you read my earlier comment clearly mentioned, *FULL OUTER JOIN, which is not present in MySQL it seems. But work around is , use LEFT and UNION together*

Comment: sir one simple question... about union... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433329/subqueries-basic-error-before-execute