# Subqueries basic error before execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't whats issue with this query and after multiple times trying I'm unable to run. Kindly  point out whats wrong with this how can  I fix that. Thanks.

```
   SELECT 
     cd.dr
    FROM
    (
     (SELECT SUM(cc.credit_amount) AS cr FROM cust_credit cc) cc
      UNION  
     (SELECT  SUM(cd.debit_amount) AS dr FROM cust_debit cd ) cd  
     )
```

The error is.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cd  ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

Comment: I suspect you're using phpMyAdmin. It adds `LIMIT 0, 25` to all queries to implement pagination in the result viewer.

Comment: you can't refer to subqueries in a `UNION` using aliases.

Answer (score 3):

You can't give aliases to subqueries in a `UNION`, and you can't refer to results from the subqueries using an alias. And the column aliases in a `UNION` always come from the aliases in the first subquery, so you can't refer to `dr`.

What you can do is:

```
SELECT amount
FROM (
    SELECT 'cc' AS type, SUM(credit_amount) as amount FROM cust_credit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cd' AS type, SUM(debit_amount) AS amount FROM cust_debit
) x
WHERE type = 'cd'
```

Or instead of using `UNION`, you can put the queries in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT dr AS amount
FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT SUM(credit_amount) FROM cust_credit) AS cr,
           (SELECT SUM(debit_amount) FROM cust_debit) AS dr
) x
```

Comment: both of queries are giving error `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: @Newbees he omitted a final `AS somealias` after the last parenthesis in each example.